# seleniumerror while executing below code

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I little help here will be appreciated.I am simply trying to open a site using selenium and here is the code. Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException error.

```
   package pkg1;

   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
   //import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


   public class training1 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\SeleniumTools\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        System.out.println("Welcome to Selenium");
        driver.get("https://in.yahoo.com/");

    }

}

----- Error -----
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:738)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:330)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:124)
    at pkg1.training1.main(training1.java:14)
```

Answer (score 1):

You must set path of the chromedriver.exe before calling `new ChromeDriver()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\SeleniumTools\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    System.out.println("Welcome to Selenium");
    driver.get("https://in.yahoo.com/");
}
```